# Selected navigation menu items missing background color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is how Web Application's tabs are suppose to look like when they are selected or hovered over:

[image]

and this is what they look like now:

[image]

The culprit I have found is that the `.nav .youarehere` list item's style is been overridden by the sprite styles, which have higher specificity. The following properties are the important ones that are been overridden:

```
.nav .youarehere {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    background-image: none;
}
```

In addition, I find this ruleset puzzling:

```
.youarehere a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Using Jin's original design screenshot, the selected tabs are suppose to have `#445A70` font color, not pure white, which would have very low contrast with the light gray background.

I suspect all this may have something to do with [a backend change to the way CSS files are been served for StackExchange 2.0 sites](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/414460#414460).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is on production now. Please refresh browser.